# 'HTMLParser' object has no attribute 'save_bgn'

Tags: python, python-3.x, html-parsing

I am using Python 3.6 and trying to edit the old code that used htmllib. I see that this module has been replaced, and that to call the parser, I need to use

```
from html.parser import HTMLParser
```

The code I am editing is as follows:

```
def parse_sentences(s):
    p = HTMLParser()
    p.save_bgn()
    try:
        p.feed(s)
    except:
        return s
    return p.save_end()
```

I get an error `'HTMLParser' object has no attribute 'save_bgn'`

I cannot find what substitutes the save_bgn() and save_end() in Python 3.6 and need help figuring it out.

Comment: HTMLParser does not have a `save_bgn` method.

Comment: what can I use to substitute it?